# Grid area seems to be ignored, how do I get it working?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I already read previous questions on number of columns. That doesn't seem to be the issue in mine.

Here's my code:

```css
    #agenda div.item {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-areas:
        "time h3 h3 h3 h3 aside"
        "span h3 h3 h3 h3 aside"
        "blank h3 h3 h3 h3 aside"
        "blank p p p blank blank";
    }

    div.item {
      margin: 1em;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #agenda time,
    #agenda span,
    #agenda h3,
    #agenda p,
    #agenda aside {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 100%;
      padding: .5em;
    }

    #agenda time {
      grid-area: "time";
      background: red;
    }

    #agenda span {
      grid-area: "span";
      background: green;
    }

    #agenda h3 {
      grid-area: "h3";
      margin: 0;
      background: blue;
    }

    #agenda p {
      grid-area: "p";
      margin: 0;
      background: orange;
    }

    #agenda aside {
      grid-area: "aside";
      background: yellow;
    }
```

```html
  <section id="agenda">

    <div class="item">
      <time>10:00 AM ET</time>
      <h3>The Genius I Was Yesterday</h3>
      <aside>Output: Stuff</aside>
      <span>30 minutes</span>
      <p>Others: Observing</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <time>10:30 AM ET</time>
      <h3>BREAK</h3>
      <aside></aside>
      <span>15 minutes</span>
      <p>Others: Quick Huddle</p>
    </div>

  </section>
```

I also noticed the order matters. If I rearrange the HTML it doesn't reflow according to the grid-template-layout.

Comment: (1) grid template should be rectangular AND contiguous (2) there is no quotes when using grid-area

Comment: Taking away 'blank' and quotes from grid-area rules didn't work. Did I misunderstand? Can you copy my code and change it?

Comment: Baaahhh! The blank, which I was intentionally leaving blank, is not rectangular. Thank you! : )

Comment: Replace the `blank` with `.`. Dots will work.

Comment: @TemaniAfif MDN says quote areas, the quotes are required: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Layout_using_Named_Grid_Lines#implicit_grid_lines_from_named_areas

Comment: @run_the_race not sure where you are reading this but if you check closely the link you sent you will see that MDN is not using quotes at all

Comment: @TemaniAfif, we must be mis understanding each other then, here: The link quotes each line, search for this text:  `grid-template-areas:
    "hd hd hd hd   hd   hd   hd   hd   hd"
    "sd sd sd main main main main main main"
    "ft ft ft ft   ft   ft   ft   ft   ft";`

Comment: @run_the_race in my comment I said : *there is no quotes when using grid-area* (also check the duplicate to understand what I meant)

Comment: @TemaniAfif okay my mistake, I see you are talking about when inserting the item with `grid-area`, not `grid-template-areas`. Thanks for that.